# Row min/max in Spyder

Tags: spyder

Is there a way to show row min/max in Spyder's Variable Explorer like there is an option for column's min/max?

I have a dataframe with metrics from different sources in the columns and would like to compare them visually using the Variable Explorer.

The columns are fewer than the rows, so I would like to not transpose the dataframe in order to look at the min/max of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, there's no option to do that. Besides, that option only works for arrays, not dataframes.

If you're interested on this, please open an issue [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/issues). However, it could take us several months to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Carlos. Columns min/max does work in my dataframe btw.